# Could not obtain connection to query metadata

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, gradle, lombok

I am making a java application using spring boot with gradle and lombok. Right now I am having difficulties setting up the connection to the database.
this is in my resources.db.migration:

CREATE TABLE users

```
(
    id        int                                NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    role      enum('CUSTOMER','TRAINER','ADMINISTRATION') NOT NULL,
    email     varchar(45)                        NOT NULL,
    password  varchar(200)                       NOT NULL,
    firstName varchar(45)                        NOT NULL,
    lastName  varchar(45)                        NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE(email)
);
```

and this is my resources:

```
application.properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hiddenName
spring.datasource.username=hiddenUsername
spring.datasource.password=hiddenPassword
```

and this is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.13.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'HiddenName'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {


    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.11'
    testImplementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
   testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.20.2'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.20.2'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
   implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'

    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.30'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.11'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.10'
   compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'



your text
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Every time I run the program I get the error "Could not obtain connection to query metadata". What am I doing wrong and what is the fix?

I expect that the connection will be possible and that the program will compile.

Comment: I don't think the stuff you pasted is relevant to the error you get. There should be a stack trace or similar someplace; essentially that error means: I tried to connect to the database and I couldn't connect; therefore, I can't get the metadata (which is 'which tables exist in the db already', for example). The problem is presumably in how you auth to your database, or if the database isn't running, etc. Which requires knowing your DB, how auth is set up, and so on.

Comment: Would it be this that you are talking about?:  Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JPAExerciseRepository' defined in org.example.persistence.JPAExerciseRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.example.persistence.entity.ExerciseEntity

Comment: That's certainly an interesting error. It sounds like that is a second, unrelated problem. You should edit the question and include it.